# Custom colorbar with ticklabels from file and rounded numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm trying to create an individual standalone colorbar and label the colors with values from a file I'd like to load with `\pgfplotstableread`. I already got quite far, but all I learned about number precision, does not work.

This is what I got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.txt}
D   d   K   k   
0.000000    0   0.400000    1400000.000000
0.400000    805.267394  0.400000    1400000.000000
0.950000    1912.510060 0.400000    1400000.000000
1.720000    3462.649793 0.400000    1400000.000000
2.790000    5616.740071 0.400000    1400000.000000
4.290000    8636.492797 0.400000    1400000.000000
6.390000    12864.146614    0.400000    1400000.000000
9.310000    18742.598588    0.400000    1400000.000000
13.390000   26956.326003    0.400000    1400000.000000
19.090000   38431.386363    0.400000    1400000.000000
NaN NaN NaN NaN
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\centering

\pgfplotstableread[skip first n=1]{testdata.txt}\DkC

\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[
    colormap/viridis,
    xminorgrids=false,
    parent axis width/.initial=15cm,
    parent axis height/.initial=1cm,
    point meta min=1,
    point meta max=11,
    colorbar sampled,
    colorbar horizontal,
    colorbar style={
        samples=11,
        xlabel=$D$,
        yshift=2mm,
        xtick={1.5,...,9.5,10.5},
        xticklabels from table = {\DkC}{d},
        xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=0},
    }
]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I'd like to get the numbers rounded with `precision=0` obviously. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Here precision doesn't work, because `xticklabels from table` does not necessarily contain numbers. The manual states: "The behavior of `xticklabels from table` is the same as if the column <colname> would have been provided as comma separated list to `xticklabels`. This means the column can contain text, TeX
macros or even math mode."

Comment: @StefanPinnow I figured now also that this is the reason. I'm trying to find out, if I could parse every value through `\pgfmathparse` or find a solution with `\pgfplotstableread`.